# Wierd line that disappears in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

There's a line in my project that I don't want. I dont know how it got there, and I don't know how to remove it. It just sits there. If I right-click on it, it says that it belongs to an object on the opposite side of where this line is!
[image]

If I enter edit mode, (which is what I did when I tried to remove it,) it disappears!

Does anybody know what this might be, or even better, how to fix it?

Comment: Try pressing Alt+H while in Edit mode for that object.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some stray edges.  Go into edit mode and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to select the non manifold geometry and then press <kbd>x</kbd> delete it. This can't be done in face select mode.

Comment: That's correct but if geometry is hidden (which probably is the case in the question) it won't be selected.

Comment: Thats a good point.  I saw the curve modifier and assumed the vertices were being moved in object mode.